# Woocommerce add to cart button not add item on cart when product open in fancybox

Tags: wordpress, iframe, woocommerce

I create custom shop page which display list of product based on category. When click on product title that product open in fancy-box with all details. I click on add to cart button i got success message but product not add on cart. If one product add cart and after that i add new product using fancy-box its work fine.
Please let me know how to solve this issue.

Comment: Do remember that the 'add to cart' JS does not automatically work on items that are added to the DOM after page load (ie: things that appear in a fancybox). You would need to re-trigger that somehow... though I would probably recommend just getting [Quick View](http://www.woothemes.com/products/woocommerce-quick-view).

Comment: Thanks for your response but also i get solution. I can just right ob_start() on top of my file and its work nice for me now